# Inbalanced Dataset for Classification Report?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, multilabel-classification

I am trying to classify a model to deduce sentiment from text. My two labels are "1" for positive, and "0" for negative. When classification report is ran it produces this output:

```
            precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.39      1.00      0.57      1081
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00      1660

    accuracy                           0.39      2741
   macro avg       0.20      0.50      0.28      2741
weighted avg       0.16      0.39      0.22      2741
```

So by the looks of it, it doesn't seem to classify label 1. Looking at other Stack Overflow posts I thought it was an unbalanced dataset problem but it doesn't seem the case. To my understanding there seems to be more data for label 1 than label 0 so I am quite confused as to the issue here.

Below are the relevant code snippets

```
import time
#Import the DecisionTreeeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
# Load from the filename
word2vec_df = pd.read_csv(word2vec_filename)
#Initialize the model
clf_decision_word2vec = DecisionTreeClassifier()

start_time = time.time()
# Fit the model
clf_decision_word2vec.fit(word2vec_df, Y_train['Sentiment'])
print("Time taken to fit the model with word2vec vectors: " + str(time.time() - start_time))
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
test_features_word2vec = []
for index, row in X_test.iterrows():
    model_vector = np.mean([sg_w2v_model[token] for token in row['stemmed_tokens']], axis=0)
    if type(model_vector) is list:
        test_features_word2vec.append(model_vector)
    else:
        test_features_word2vec.append(np.array([0 for i in range(1000)]))
test_predictions_word2vec = clf_decision_word2vec.predict(test_features_word2vec)
print(classification_report(Y_test['Sentiment'],test_predictions_word2vec))
for num in test_predictions_word2vec:
  print(num)
```

At the end of that code snippet I added a for loop to quickly test to see what data was in test_predictions_word2vec and it looks like all zeroes.

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Not too sure what happened where all the 1s were left out (I only included a small subset here to show the 0s. Looking at the full output on my console there was no 1s present).

I'm assuming it is because of this line here:

```
test_features_word2vec.append(np.array([0 for i in range(1000)]))
```

Where it looks like it just appending 0s. Any help in this issue will be greatly appreciated!

P.S snippet for test-train split and output:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Train Test Split Function
def split_train_test(split_data, test_size=0.3, shuffle_state=True):
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(split_data[['movie_title',  'critics_consensus',    'tomatometer_status',   'tokenized_text',   'stemmed_tokens']], 
                                                        split_data['Sentiment'], 
                                                        shuffle=shuffle_state,
                                                        test_size=test_size, 
                                                        random_state=42)
    print("Value counts for Train sentiments")
    print(Y_train.value_counts())
    print("Value counts for Test sentiments")
    print(Y_test.value_counts())
    print(type(X_train))
    print(type(Y_train))
    X_train = X_train.reset_index()
    X_test = X_test.reset_index()
    Y_train = Y_train.to_frame()
    Y_train = Y_train.reset_index()
    Y_test = Y_test.to_frame()
    Y_test = Y_test.reset_index()
    print(X_train.head())

    

    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test

# Call the train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = split_train_test(split_data)
```

```
Value counts for Train sentiments
1    3805
0    2588
Name: Sentiment, dtype: int64
Value counts for Test sentiments
1    1660
0    1081
```

EDIT: Adding output of 'word2vec_df'

```
Time taken to fit the model with word2vec vectors: 18.75066113471985
             0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0     0.009097 -0.014559 -0.021197  0.060744 -0.019707  0.102395  0.032876   
1     0.008102 -0.003382 -0.014465  0.066731 -0.024593  0.085185  0.023677   
2     0.013941 -0.005870 -0.001550  0.071456 -0.013130  0.094142  0.043876   
3     0.010195 -0.012312 -0.006310  0.069745 -0.012042  0.091056  0.034140   
4     0.006570 -0.010348 -0.016157  0.063258 -0.029932  0.098463  0.034469   
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
6388  0.000616 -0.000732 -0.006287  0.063298 -0.024651  0.055185 -0.000368   
6389  0.010891 -0.007447 -0.025401  0.063245 -0.028681  0.100588  0.029031   
6390  0.009561 -0.007456 -0.017953  0.076449 -0.029962  0.092921  0.040811   
6391  0.012995 -0.008843 -0.013079  0.058345 -0.027885  0.095623  0.024361   
6392  0.007881  0.003228 -0.013990  0.065434 -0.017051  0.090314  0.031072   

             7         8         9  ...       990       991       992  \
0     0.068392  0.120006  0.038360  ... -0.009643 -0.062597 -0.027641   
1     0.073042  0.101701  0.030647  ... -0.016221 -0.058624 -0.030524   
2     0.061665  0.117775  0.014894  ... -0.017982 -0.065756 -0.044015   
3     0.057861  0.117489  0.015533  ... -0.016098 -0.065427 -0.039047   
4     0.071677  0.100755  0.029278  ... -0.022267 -0.050894 -0.030283   
...        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...   
6388  0.058975  0.085394  0.028661  ... -0.016373 -0.050449 -0.008869   
6389  0.066502  0.106864  0.035051  ... -0.019567 -0.069977 -0.039586   
6390  0.061507  0.120290  0.030399  ...  0.000696 -0.054154 -0.041237   
6391  0.081338  0.111422  0.034755  ... -0.019699 -0.060718 -0.032540   
6392  0.054831  0.125640  0.032965  ... -0.002751 -0.084193 -0.040441   

           993       994       995       996       997       998       999  
0     0.078252  0.034909 -0.007387  0.057867 -0.052527 -0.072866 -0.010007  
1     0.075942  0.039987 -0.012127  0.042507 -0.054933 -0.072949 -0.010296  
2     0.065845  0.057452  0.002048  0.057100 -0.048846 -0.097791 -0.007207  
3     0.059275  0.051354  0.000843  0.050823 -0.046350 -0.090028 -0.005206  
4     0.066598  0.034786 -0.000143  0.056494 -0.046227 -0.070975 -0.007705  
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
6388  0.061066  0.017348 -0.018751  0.041088 -0.042949 -0.049911 -0.019149  
6389  0.071031  0.043249 -0.002368  0.040806 -0.046722 -0.085424  0.005255  
6390  0.076632  0.065442 -0.000805  0.050374 -0.047395 -0.085746  0.006119  
6391  0.083535  0.030460 -0.004143  0.047868 -0.058123 -0.069077 -0.012215  
6392  0.077906  0.075460 -0.013605  0.056237 -0.059329 -0.093779 -0.009383  

[6393 rows x 1000 columns]
```

Comment: And you show the  word2vec_df? I am curious of this format.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton
This is the average of all word vectors in a sentence:
`[-7.83671997e-03 -7.36686029e-03 -2.28813626e-02  6.75179139e-02
 -1.95912011e-02  8.27067047e-02  3.29648592e-02  4.37834449e-02
  1.07595101e-01  3.09796631e-02 -1.28445938e-01  6.40949756e-02
 -3.87786031e-02 -1.08702026e-01  2.13950407e-02 -3.38640176e-02
 -3.60674337e-02  4.96328846e-02 -2.38844715e-02  4.79324609e-02
  2.22943649e-02  2.87785064e-02 -3.48913274e-03 -3.68809439e-02...]`

Comment: @BenjaminBreton 
Code snippet:
`sg_w2v_model = Word2Vec.load(word2vec_model_file)
# Unique ID of the word
print("Index of the word 'action':")
print(sg_w2v_model.wv.vocab["action"].index)
print(len(sg_w2v_model.wv.vocab))
# Print the size of the word2vec vector for one word
print("Length of the vector generated for a word")
print(len(sg_w2v_model['action']))
print("Print the length after taking average of all word vectors in a sentence:")
print(np.mean([sg_w2v_model[token] for token in split_data['stemmed_tokens'][0]], axis=0))`

Comment: can you add the result of print(word2vec_df) to the question ? I think you might have a format issue. And usually, we add info to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: noted and apologies, edited it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct:

```py
np.array([0 for i in range(1000)])
```

Creates an array full of zeros.

You should try:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
test_features_word2vec = []

averaged_test_vector = X_test['stemmed_tokens'].apply(
        lambda x: np.mean([sg_w2v_model[tok] for tok in x], axis=0) 
    ).tolist()

averaged_test_vector = np.vstack(averaged_test_vector)

test_predictions_word2vec = clf_decision_word2vec.predict(test_features_word2vec)
print(classification_report(Y_test['Sentiment'],test_predictions_word2vec))
```

Generally speaking, I would use embeddings of lower dimension if available.
1000 is a lot for a small dataset.
And I wouldn't use `DecisionTreeClassifier` as it overfits quickly.
I would start with `LinearSVC` or `RandomForrestClassifier`.

Comment: That makes sense, any reason why I may be getting a Value Error?
`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
`
Does it have to do with my dataset not being in a 2D array?

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: `test_predictions_word2vec = clf_decision_word2vec.predict(test_features_word2vec)
`

Comment: averaged_test_vector whould be  a matrix of dimension (number of exemples, dimension of the embedding), I added a np.vstack to set the dimensions corerctly, byt it might differ based on the way your sg_w2v_model[tok] works.